# Where do I write my database permissions?

Tags: sql, permissions, sql-grant

I have several scripts for my database, one for each CREATE TABLE etc. .. Now I want to handle permissions on my database and am writing several GRANT Statements. Do you have any best practiceses on where to save those ? Do you put them all in a separate script or do you include them in your CREATE TABLE scripts or do you have another solution ?

Comment: It depends on the size and complexity of the database.

Comment: So if you have a small database just put them under the CREATE TABLE scripts, if its a large one use a separate script just for permissions ?